# How to add extra comment in invoice pdf in magento2 backend?

Tags: magento2, invoice-pdf

I know the override way

> vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php

but have any other better way to insert extra filed in pdf

because i want to add lots different filed in different modules in pdf

Comment: can you add the screenshot where you want to put the comment